# Area between curves $y=x^3$ and $y=x$

Tags: calculus, area, curves

I've tried to done one of my homework problems for several times, but the answer doesn't make sense to me. The question asks to find the area between $y=x^3$ and $y=x$. Those are odd functions, and I'm pretty sure that the area between their graphs should be 0. However, I keep getting 1/2 as my answer. Can anyone please check my work to see if I did something wrong?

$$
\begin{align}
A &= \int_0^1 \left(x-x^3\right) \,\operatorname{d}\!x + \int_{-1}^0 \left(x^3-x\right) \,\operatorname{d}\!x \\
  &= \left. \left( \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^4}{4} \right) \right\vert_0^1 + \left. \left( \frac{x^4}{4} - \frac{x^2}{2} \right) \right\vert_{-1}^0 \\
  &= \left( \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4} - 0 \right) + \left[ 0 - \left( \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{2} \right) \right] \\
  &= \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)+\left[-\left(\frac{-1}{4}\right)\right] \\
  &= \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{2}{4} = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}
$$

Thanks ahead!

Comment: If you took $\int_{-1}^{1} x-x^3 \, dx$ then you would indeed get zero; however, since we are taking the area integral $\int_{-1}^1 |x-x^3|\, dx$ it must be positive.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The area between two curves is always positive. See the below graph.

[image]

The area in green and orange is the area you are finding. It is always going to be positive because it *exists*. When you subtract the two curves, you are finding the area between the curves, regardless of their position relative to the x axis.

Also, you could have just multiplied one of your integrals by 2 to get the answer because they are odd functions :P

Comment: "Also, you could have just multiplied one of your integrals by 2 to get the answer because they are odd functions"
I thought this is only applicable for even functions? And thanks a lot for your response! :)

Comment: Well, it generally only applies to even functions, but that's only because you can have negative area on the left side with even functions. The area between curves is always positive.